# error: conflicting types for 'add_to_queue'

Tags: c, queue

Getting a `conflicting types` error for the `add_to_queue` function in the program.

I copied the node struct and functions.  The header file code is at the bottom.  This code (when finished should emulate 5 paging algorithms using a queue).  It is far from finished.  I'm stuck on creating the queue.

HELP!!!  Thanks.

```
#include "project2_MLL.h"


typedef struct node{
  char data[5];
  struct node* next;
  struct node* prev;
}nodes;


void make_queue(char datas[5]){
  struct node new_node;
  strcpy(new_node.data, datas);
  new_node.next = NULL;
  new_node.prev = NULL;
}

void add_to_queue(struct node *last, char* datasa[5]){
  struct node newer_node;
  strcpy(newer_node.data, datasa);
  newer_node.next = NULL;
  newer_node.prev = last->data;
  last->next = newer_node.data;
}
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int num_frames=0;
int num_page_swaps;
int* head;
int* tail;
int input;


void make_queue(char datas[5]);
void add_to_queue(struct node *last, char* datasa[5]);
void page_swap(char* frame_table[num_frames][3], char* backing_store[input], int frame_num, int page_num, char page_val);
bool in_frame(char* frame_table[num_frames][3], char page_val[5]);

int FIFO(char* frame_table[num_frames][3]);
```

Comment: The exact error message will have more detail and a precise line number.  Post the complete, exact error.

Comment: add_to_queue function prototype in header file used struct node pointer before declaration of struct node structure. You need to do forward declaration of struct node in your header file. Add "struct node;" to your header file before add_to_queue function prototype.